# Determining Software that is Already Installed

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to figure out how to determine if a software application is already installed.  I saw some ways people have done it for Software Dependencies but that does not quite do what I need.  I am using the `Get-WmiObject` in Powershell.  Here is my code so far:

```
#Check for Sophos
$MyApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -eq "Sophos Endpoint"}

#Logic To Install or Skip
if ($MyApp -eq "Sophos Endpoint"){
    Write-Output "Sophos Endpoint is already installed on this computer."
}
else{
    Write-Output "Sophos Endpoint will be installed quietly in the background"

    #Install Sophos
    SophosSetup.exe --products=antivirus,intercept --quiet
}
```

I believe I have a formatting Issue which is why my if else statement is not working properly.

EDIT:
When Sophos is present the if statement skips the else.  I believe the issue is with how `Get-WmiObject` is formatting the output to a variable.  It outputs currently as:

```
Name           
----           
Sophos Endpoint
```

Which then fails the if statement logic.  I need the `Get-WmiObject` command to just output Sophos Endpoint into the Variable `$MyApp`.

Comment: I would make it  `-like "sophos*"` instead of `-eq "sophos endpoint"` just in case there is something weird in there. Same when defining $myApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe I have a formatting Issue which is why my if else statement
>   is not working properly.

You actually have a PowerShell programming problem.  The contents of your variable is actually the quoted text below, which is not equivalent to "Sophos Endpoint".

> ```
> Name           
> ----           
> Sophos Endpoint
> ```

The following statement is true for equality operators.  **Basically, your script was doing exactly what it was supposed to since the input values were not identical to one another.**

> The equality operators (-eq, -ne) return a value of TRUE or the
>   matches when one or more of the input values is identical to the
>   specified pattern. The entire pattern must match an entire value.

Source: [Equality Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#equality-operators)

The following script will output the value of the variable and the debug message if a match to the regular expression is found.  Otherwise, it will only output a debug message.

```
#Check for Sophos
$MyApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -match "WinZip 24.0"}

if ($MyApp -match "WinZip 24.0")
{
    Write-Output $MyApp.Name
    Write-Output "WinZip is already installed on this computer."
}
else
{
    Write-Output "WinZip is already installed on this computer."
}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `$MyApp.Name` is indeed a better solution. Of course, I would still use -match, but that would simply be my personal preference.  *I am going to burrow that particular syntax.*

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Object` returns an object, not a string.

The string you want is the `.Name` attribute which will be part of `$MyApp` (since you assigned it from the output of `Get-Object`).

This should work:

```
if ($MyApp.Name -eq "Sophos Endpoint"){`
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you want is reading the product information from registry

I use the following function for that (see below)

you could then simply do:

```
$isInstalled = Get-AppVersion "Sophos Endpoint"
if(!$isInstalled) { .\SophosSetup.exe --products=antivirus,intercept --quiet }
```

The function can also handle RemoteComputers and Wildcard search, if you're not quite sure how the product is called. You can also tell it what Properties you want to get returned

The function:

```
function Get-AppVersion {

    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [string]$filter = '*', 
        [string[]]$properties = @("DisplayName", "DisplayVersion", "InstallDate"), 
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )

    $regpath = @(
        "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
        "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    )

    $sb = { 
        param ( $regpath, $filter, $properties )
        $regpath | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_ } | 
            Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ne $null -and $_.DisplayName -like $filter } | 
                Select-Object $properties 
    }

    $splat = @{}
    if ($ComputerName) { $splat['ComputerName'] = $ComputerName }

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $regpath, $filter, $properties @splat

}
```

Here are some example outputs:

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> Get-AppVersion SwyxIt!

DisplayName DisplayVersion InstallDate
----------- -------------- -----------
SwyxIt!     11.32.3220.0   20181123

PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> Get-AppVersion *swyx*

DisplayName DisplayVersion InstallDate
----------- -------------- -----------
SwyxIt!     11.32.3220.0   20181123

PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> Get-AppVersion *swyx* -ComputerName RS

DisplayName    : SwyxIt!
DisplayVersion : 11.32.3220.0
InstallDate    : 20181129
PSComputerName : RS
RunspaceId     : ed097948-c722-4235-aa64-9b0045c5478f


PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> Get-AppVersion dkgfmnslkf
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> Get-AppVersion *swyx* -properties *

AuthorizedCDFPrefix :
Comments            : SwyxIt! macht aus Ihrem PC ein komfortables und leicht zu nutzendes Telefon.
Contact             :
DisplayVersion      : 11.32.3220.0
HelpLink            :
HelpTelephone       :
InstallDate         : 20181123
InstallLocation     : C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\
InstallSource       : Z:\Software\q-z\Swyx\SwyxWare 11.32.0.0\SwyxIt!\x64\Deutsch\
ModifyPath          : MsiExec.exe /I{1BA548A7-D32F-4D06-B9A9-451947814967}
Publisher           : Swyx Solutions GmbH
Readme              : C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\Readme.rtf
Size                :
EstimatedSize       : 318937
UninstallString     : MsiExec.exe /I{1BA548A7-D32F-4D06-B9A9-451947814967}
URLInfoAbout        :
URLUpdateInfo       : http://www.swyx.de/support/update.html?product=SwyxIt!&version=11.32.3220.0&language=1031
VersionMajor        : 11
VersionMinor        : 32
WindowsInstaller    : 1
Version             : 186649748
Language            : 1031
DisplayName         : SwyxIt!
PSPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1BA548A7-D32F-4D06-B9A9-451947814967}
PSParentPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName         : {1BA548A7-D32F-4D06-B9A9-451947814967}
PSDrive             : HKLM
PSProvider          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry


PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts>
```